# how to store the data of instances of a owl ontology

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

I want to build a wind turbine ontology with protege.
There is a class named **Blade** and many instances of this class.
It’s better to add all these instances or add only one instances and link to a database? The database is to store the date of Blade.

Comment: and if you link to a database, what then? How can any tool make use of this? "better" in terms of what? Just adding a link to a database is totally black-box for any standard OWL tool. But sure, if you have some client code later on processing your own ontology and being capable of retrieving the data from some other database, then go for it.

Comment: Actually I want to know if an ontology can be used as a database? If I add too many instances to the ontology, will it make the ontology bloated?
If a large number of instances makes my ontology bad, I will create an additional database for the instance. For example I create an instance called "blade", which has a data property "Dimension", and then store the Dimension's data in the database